# how to make ICU smaller?

Tags: webkit, icu

In WebKit, it use ICU, but I don't have enough space to contain icudt42.dll. the size of icudt42.dll is about 10.4MB,but I only need Chinese language, Russian language and English language,so how can I make the icudt.dll smaller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [data customizer](http://apps.icu-project.org/datacustom/) as a nice GUI to create a customized .dat file, from which you can then build the DLL. See the [userguide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/packaging) on packaging ICU.

Answer (score 0):

Get the source code, trim it out, recompile it?